# How to clamp an Input[type="range"]

Tags: javascript, html

I want the slider to not pass a certain limit. How can I set this is HTML and also change it in javascript?

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="30">
```

I want to set it so that the slider  can never go past a certain value though the value will be there on slider i.e slider should have min:0 max:100 but never go past say 70.

Comment: What you are saying is correct, just set `min` and `max` value

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_range

Comment: Doesn't have sense in my opinion set `max="100"` and want 70 as `max` value, just put 70 as `max`.

Comment: It's not what he wants

Comment: I want 70 to be max but I want the user to know that they can go past it as well just not now? Am I making sense?

Comment: Yes, it's what you need. I have added an answer @AshutoshShinde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this could work for your case, but set the max value to 70 is better in my opinion.

```js
function test(e, el) {
  if (e.target.value > 70) el.value = 70;
  document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "range value: " + e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" style="width: 100%;" oninput="test(event, this)">
<br>
<h1>range value: 50</h1>
```

Comment: This does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for you. If the user drags the slider over to 70, we reset it to 70 again.

```html
<h1>Display a Range Field</h1>


  <label for="vol">Volume <span id="currentvalue">   </span>  (between 0 and 100):</label>
  <input type="range" id="vol" name="vol" min="0" max="100" value="30">

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("currentvalue").innerHTML = document.getElementById("vol").value;
document.getElementById("vol").addEventListener("change", function(e){
 
 if(e.target.value > 70) {
    alert("You can't pick above 70 for now!");  
    this.value = 70;
 }
 document.getElementById("currentvalue").innerHTML = e.target.value;
 e.preventDefault();
 e.stopPropagation();
})
  
</script>
```